# how to manipulate css with css module in typescript

Tags: html, css, typescript

I am write a interval slide animation in the html, using typescript to manipulate the image, this is the function:

```
let currentIndex = 0;
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
React.useEffect(() => {
    let slide = setInterval(nextImage, 3000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(slide);
    }
  }, []);

  const showImage = (index: number) => {
    images.forEach((img) => {
      img.classList.remove('active');
    });
    images[index].classList.add('active');
  }

  const nextImage = () => {
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex >= images.length) {
      currentIndex = 0;
    }
    showImage(currentIndex);
  }
```

and this is the css look like:

```
.slideshow {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: none;
}

.slideshow img.active {
    display: block;
}
```

and this is the html:

```
<div className={styles.slideshow}>
              <img src={moderncv} alt="Image 1" />
              <img src={moderncv} alt="Image 2" />
              <img src={moderncv} alt="Image 3" />
            </div>
```

but when I use this code, the img css could not changed to block, the image could not show in the web page. what should I do to manipulate the css by name when using css module? is the css name add the random string make the dynamic typescript function could not found the css by name?